# How to move the folders to new directory based on their match in csv file?

Tags: linux, command-line, csv, xargs

In my present directory I have many folders like F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10.

I have a csv file "dan.csv" in the present directory which has a column with folder names.

csv file looks like below: Column name is "id"

```
id
F1
F4
F5
F6
F8
F10
```

Based on their match in the csv file I would like to move the folders to a new directory "DAN".

To do this I tried like below:

```
xargs -a <(tail -n +2 dan.csv) -I{} sh -c '[ -d "{}" ] && mv -t DAN "{}"'
```

This didn't throw any error and also didn't move the folders into new directory "DAN".

Answer (score 0):

A simple bash `while` loop is sufficient:

```
IFS=";"
while read othercolumn1 othercolumn2 ... id ... othercolumnx
do
    mv $id DAN/
done < dan.csv
```

That reads every line from the CSV file, splits the line by the character set in the `IFS` variable, and stores each value of that line in the corresponding variables specified in the header of the while loop.

Make sure to fit the header of the while loop (where all columns are listed) to the header of your CSV file. You probably don't need the values of the other columns, but it's important to read them nevertheless, otherwise every value in the CSV would be treated as an `id` value. If your CSV file is seperated by something other than `;`, make sure to set the specific character as the `IFS=`-value before the `while` loop.

If your `dan.csv` had four columns where the id is the third one, you'd do it like this:

```
IFS=";"
while read othercolumn1 othercolumn2 id othercolumn4
do
    mv $id DAN/
done < dan.csv
```

Comment: In my csv file there is only one column "id" with folder names. So giving this way works? while read id; do mv $id DAN/; done < dan.csv

Comment: Yep, in case you have just one column, you just need to do `while read i; do ...`

Comment: I got an error like this. mv: missing destination file operand after ‘DAN/’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: Replace `mv $id DAN/` by `echo $id` for testing purposes. It should print all the folder names that are stored in the csv file without any empty lines in between. If there are empty lines, `mv` of course fails, because it needs at least 2 operands.

Comment: it prints empty lines